# Set a bool variable if program is running from Eclipse IDE or compiled binary java

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to set a bool variable if my java program is running from the IDE or if the program is running from the compiled binary java.

There is a bug that the:

```
System.out.print("test\r");
```

will not carriage return in Eclipse IDE, but it behaves corretly if run in the cmd command window.

I would like to make a code to switch between `print` methods depending on where it's ran from.

I'm not considering upgrading to the new Eclipse version that has fixed this problem yet.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why do you need a \r in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Your compiled jar is usually in a different directory than your IDE development environment. Create a file called `debugFlag.txt` in the root of your development directory, then in your Main file call:

```
public static final boolean IS_DEBUG = (new File(System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) + "/debugFlag.txt" )).exists();
```

Comment: Why not just `new File("debugFlag.txt").exists()`, i.e. specify a relative path?

Comment: Using the "user.dir" property value ensures that you are getting the actual running directory of your application, and that that file is not part of your application. Using just the file name is relative to the package (ie: directory) of the class file, which means that you have an extraneous file in your application. Doing this is really cheap as it is only run once when the application starts, then you can do ```Main.IS_DEBUG``` everywhere.

Comment: *"Using just the file name is relative to the package"* No it's not. You have to use `Class::getResourceAsStream()` to get the content of a file next to the class, i.e. located on the classpath. Javadoc of [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) says *"By default the classes in the `java.io` package always resolve **relative** pathnames against the **current user directory**. This directory is named by the system property **`user.dir`**, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked."*

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use a system property to control whether to print `\r`.

E.g. use `print.return=false`.

```java
boolean printReturn = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("print.return", "true"));
if (printReturn)
    System.out.print("test\r");
```

When run without specifying the property, it defaults to true, so simply running in a command prompt will print.

You then update the Run Configuration in Eclipse, on the `Arguments` tab, add this line to the `VM arguments` box:

```
-Dprint.return=false
```

You only need to do that once, so it's a easy one-time config and program will now not print when running from Eclipse, but will print when running from command prompt, or when double-clicking a runnable jar.

If you use other environments that also has trouble with `\r`, you now have to option to disable printing when running there too, instead of hard-coding an "Eclipse-only" feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to spend time on retrocomputing:

```
boolean insideEclipse = System.console() == null;
```